# Iterate over a subset of a vector using indices

Tags: r, file, for-loop, file-io, vector

I can iterate over all the files in a directory. However, I want to iterate over certain files instead of all the files. I want to use indices.

I want to do this by using a `file_id` vector. Each vector element would be index in "files".

For example: I have 500 total files in a directory, and I only want to iterate three files which are files 2,4,15. I generated a vector called `file_id = c(2, 4, 15)`. Now, how can I iterate over only these files or indices, such as `files[2]`, `files[4]`, `files[15]` which will get data only from files 2, 4, and 15, instead of all 500 files.

```
#get a list of all the files in directory.
files <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE) 

#iterate over all the files in directory, and get file data
for (item in files){
    filedata <- read.csv(item)
}

#What I want to do is only iterate over following files indicated in file_id vector. That will open files 2,4, and 15 nothing else.
file_id = c(2, 4, 31)
```

Comment: `files <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)[c(1,4,15)]` and then use your `loop`

Comment: But you should be prepared for the files you're interested in to change order in `list.files`. If you explain a little bit more about your problem, we could help you find a more robust approach.

Comment: Thanks Jilber and Peyton. it solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

When you iterate inside a `for` loop, the syntax is:

```
for(index in SET)
```

where `index` is your iterator and `SET` is anything that can be converted to a vector (even a matrix or array, it'll loop over each element).

```
#get a list of all the files in directory.
files <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE) 

file_id = c(2, 4, 31)

#iterate over all the files in directory, and get file data
for (i in file_id){
    filedata <- read.csv(files[i])
}
```

here, you only need to modify `file_id` to loop over that specific files.

Answer (score 2):

Find all files then index them using the `[]` operator, as a normal array.

```
all.files <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE) 
file_id <- c(2, 4, 31)
for (item in all.files[file_id])
    {
    filedata <- read.csv(item)
    }
```

For increased readibility I would tend to avoid indexing the function call directly, as suggested in the comments.

Even better, what you should do is dump the `for` loop altogether and use one of the `*apply` function.

For instance

```
all.files <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE) 
file_id <- c(2, 4, 31)
filedata <- sapply(all.files[file_id], function(f)
    {
    read.csv(f)
    })
```

This will return a list with an element per file. You can then access each file's content using the `[[]]` operator.

For instance

```
filedata[[2]]
```

will return the content of the second file (i.e. that with id 4)