# Transforming numerical variables in a dataframe with a function

Tags: r

#### Background

This is an attempt to improve a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906061/transforming-all-numerical-variables-in-a-dataframe-with-a-function). The idea is to create a function where I pass a dataframe and optionally a vector with variable names, the function then iterate over the variables in the dataframe, if they are numeric they are transformed. If the vector of names is also passed, only the ones in the list are iterated.

#### Tools used

- In order to create an "optional" argument I used the missing() function. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370249/correct-way-to-specifiy-optional-arguments-in-r-functions).
- The syntax to iterate over the vector was inspired from this dicussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206635/iterate-over-a-subset-of-a-vector-using-indices).

#### Code & where I am stuck:

```
transformDivideThousand <- function(data_frame, listofvars){
    if (missing(listofvars)) {
        data_frame[, sapply(data_frame, is.numeric)] =
        data_frame[, sapply(data_frame, is.numeric)]/1000
    } else {
        for (i in names(data_frame)) {
            for (i in listofvars) {
                data_frame[[i]]<-data_frame[[i]]/1000
            }
        }
    }
    return(data_frame)
}
```

The call would look like:

```
test <- transformDivideThousand(cases, c("col2", "col3", "col15"))
```

#### Question

- What I am getting wrong on that code? I managed to make the optional argument work, but there is something wrong in the code. When I test it the variables from the list are converted to zeros.

#### Cautionary suggestion

- If you are down-voting the question, at very least justify why!

Comment: Maybe `if (i %in% listofvariables) {` ? See [set](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do:

```
# data
 head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

the function

```
foo_divide <- function(x, y){
  foo <- function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) x/1000 else x # function to divide numeric columns by 1000
  if(missing(y)) y <- 1:ncol(x) # set y if missing
  x[, y] <-  lapply(x[, y], foo)
  as.data.frame(x) # return
}
```

no listofvars

```
head(foo_divide(iris))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1       0.0051      0.0035       0.0014       2e-04  setosa
2       0.0049      0.0030       0.0014       2e-04  setosa
3       0.0047      0.0032       0.0013       2e-04  setosa
4       0.0046      0.0031       0.0015       2e-04  setosa
5       0.0050      0.0036       0.0014       2e-04  setosa
6       0.0054      0.0039       0.0017       4e-04  setosa
```

plus listofvars

```
 head(foo_divide(iris, c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")))
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5       0.0014       2e-04  setosa
2          4.9         3.0       0.0014       2e-04  setosa
3          4.7         3.2       0.0013       2e-04  setosa
4          4.6         3.1       0.0015       2e-04  setosa
5          5.0         3.6       0.0014       2e-04  setosa
6          5.4         3.9       0.0017       4e-04  setosa
```

You can also use a numeric vector to specify the columns

```
foo_divide(iris, 1:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, with the help from the comments:

```
################################################################################
#
# transformDivideThousand(dataframe, optional = vectorListOfVariables)
#
# Definition: This function applies a transformation, dividing variables by
# 1000. If the vector is passed it applies the transformation to all variables
# in the dataframe.
#
# Example: df <- transformDivideThousand (cases, c("label1","label2"))
#
################################################################################
transformDivideThousand <- function(data_frame, listofvars){
    if (missing(listofvars)) {
        data_frame[, sapply(data_frame, is.numeric)] =
        data_frame[, sapply(data_frame, is.numeric)]/1000
    } else {
        for (i in names(data_frame)) {
            if (i %in% listofvars) {
                data_frame[,i] = data_frame[,i]/1000
            }
        }
    }
    return(data_frame)
}
```